# Changing TextEditor background color in SwiftUI for macOS

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, nstextfield

I would like to change the background color of a SwiftUI text editor on macOS.
Is there a variant for the code below (used for iOS) to work for NSTextField instead of UITextView?

Thanks.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    init() {
        UITextView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
    }

    var body: some View {
        TextEditor(text: .constant("Placeholder"))
            .background(Color.red)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have just posted an answer for that issue on a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65865881/11878069)

With the help of extension, you can clear the default background Color of the NSTextView class and then use `.background` modifier in SwiftUI like this

```
extension NSTextView {
    open override var frame: CGRect {
        didSet {
            backgroundColor = .clear //<<here clear
            drawsBackground = true
        }

    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var string: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        TextEditor(text: $string)
            .textFieldStyle(PlainTextFieldStyle())
            .background(Color.red) //<< here red
    }
}
```

Comment: Amazing! works in ios too

Answer (score -7):

Like how this looks in swift?

```
myNSTextField.drawsBackground = true
myNSTextField.backgroundColor = NSColor.red
```

What about:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var myText: String = "blah blah blah"
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            TextField("Enter text", text: $myText)
            .background(Color.red)

        }.padding()
    
    }
}
```