# RoundedRectangle background colour does not crop and TextEditor transparent background

Tags: swiftui

I have a messaging interface. When user types in to the `texteditor` it will be append to `messagesDBArray` and will be displayed in `textview`. Once new messages are there it should scroll to the bottom. But I'm having issues.

**Errors:** no errors

1. `RoundedRectangle` background colour green overflows from corners (does not `crop` as rounded)
2. `TextEditor` (not textview) is not `transparent` (so it can have rounded rectangle color underneath)
3. `proxy.scrollTo(id, anchor: .bottom)` does not scrolls to the last message.

```
import SwiftUI
    
final class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var messagesDBArray : [SingleMessageBubbleModel] = []
}
    
struct SingleMessageBubbleModel: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var text: String
    var received: Bool
    var timeStamp: Date
}
    
var messagesDBArray : [SingleMessageBubbleModel] = []
    
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject private var messageArrayObservedObject = ViewModel()
        
    @State private var showOnTheSpotMessaging: Bool = true
    @State var textTyped: String = ""
        
    var body: some View {
    VStack (alignment: .center) {    
        ZStack (alignment: .center) {      
            HStack () {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25, style: .continuous)
                    .stroke(Color.brown, lineWidth: 1)
                    .frame(width: 300, alignment: Alignment.top )
                    .padding([.bottom], 5)
                    .clipped()
                    .background(Color.green)        
            }
            HStack () {
                ScrollViewReader { proxy in
                    ScrollView {
                        LazyVStack {
                            ForEach(
                                messageArrayObservedObject.messagesDBArray,
                                id: \.id
                            ) {
                                message in MessageBubble(message: message)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .frame(alignment: .center)
                    .background(Color.clear)
                    .padding (.vertical, 5)
                    .padding (.horizontal,5)
                    .padding(.bottom, 5)
                    
                    .onChange(
                        of: messageArrayObservedObject.messagesDBArray.count
                    ) { id in
                        // When the lastMessageId changes, scroll to the bottom of the conversation
                        withAnimation {
                            proxy.scrollTo(id, anchor: .bottom)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .frame( height: 200, alignment: .center)
            }
            .frame(width: 295, alignment: Alignment.center )  
        } 
        HStack () {
            VStack {    
                ZStack (alignment: .center) {
                    HStack () {
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25, style: .continuous)
                            .stroke(Color.brown , lineWidth: 1)
                            .frame(width: 295, alignment: Alignment.top )
                            .padding([.bottom], 5)
                            .clipped()
                            .background(Color.green)
                            // .background(Color("#E5F2E4"))
                    }
                    HStack () {
                        TextEditor (text: $textTyped)
                            .frame(height: 200, alignment: .leading)
                            .padding(.horizontal, 10)
                            .background(.clear)
                        }
                    }
                    .frame(width: 290, alignment: Alignment.top )
                    .padding(.top, 5)
                }
            }   
        }
    }
    struct MessageBubble: View {
        var message: SingleMessageBubbleModel
        @State private var showTime = false
        
        var body: some View {
            VStack(alignment: message.received ? .leading : .trailing) {
                HStack {
                    Text(message.text)
                        .padding()
                        .background(message.received ? Color.gray : Color.blue)
                        .cornerRadius(30)
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: 300, alignment: message.received ? .leading : .trailing)
                .onTapGesture {
                    withAnimation {
                    showTime.toggle()
                }
            }  
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: message.received ? .leading : .trailing)
        .padding(message.received ? .leading : .trailing)
        .padding(.horizontal, 4)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for the first error you should use that code instead of your code where you make a background with RoundRectangle the same to your base rectangle and make the fill of that the color you want which is green

```
              RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25, style: .continuous)
                    .stroke(Color.brown, lineWidth: 1).background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25).fill(Color.green))
                     .frame(width: 300, alignment: Alignment.top )
                     .padding([.bottom], 5)
                     .clipped()
```

the second issue in your ContentView you should init your UITextView background color to clear and after that make your textEditor Color clear using that code

```
    init() {
       UITextView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
   }
```

and make your textEditor background clear

```
TextEditor (text: $textTyped)
                .frame(height: 200, alignment: .leading)
                .padding(.horizontal, 10)
                .background(Color.clear)
```

and the third issue is that i think you are using the array count but you should use the id of each message so when if we suppose that the last message-id is **728398** in your onChange

```
onChange(of: messageArrayObservedObject.messagesDBArray.count) { id in
                // When the lastMessageId changes, scroll to the bottom of the conversation
                withAnimation {
                    print("ididididid\(id)")
                    proxy.scrollTo(messageArrayObservedObject.messagesDBArray.last, anchor: .bottom)
                }
            }
```

your are using the ( messageArrayObservedObject.messagesDBArray.count )counts of messages like **5** message so you are scrolling to **5** not to the id of message which is **728398**

Comment: For the 3rd one, it throws an error when I try to feed the id to a variable `lastMessageId` `ForEach(messageArrayObservedObject.messagesDBArray, id: \.id) { message in
                                           MessageBubble(message: message)
                                           lastMessageID = message.id
                                            
                                       }`  Error thrown is `Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'` and how to retrieve the last item id in the array?

Comment: For the 2nd one with `init()`, it throws an error `Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties`

Comment: For the third try to use array.last it will get the last element on array

Comment: For the 2nd try to see that  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65865182/transparent-background-for-texteditor-in-swiftui  it should help

Comment: `.onChange(of: messageArrayObservedObject.messagesDBArray.last?.id) { id in
                                            proxy.scrollTo(id, anchor: .bottom)
                                       }` doesn't work

Comment: should be like that.                                                                                    
.onChange(of: messageArrayObservedObject.messagesDBArray) { id in                                             proxy.scrollTo(messageArrayObservedObject.messagesDBArray.last, anchor: .bottom)

Comment: then it throws error : `Struct 'ScrollViewProxy' requires that 'SingleMessageBubbleModel' conform to 'Hashable'`

Comment: confirm your SingleMessageBubbleModel to Hashable protocol like that in struct SingleMessageBubbleModel : Hashable

Comment: error is gone but it still does not scroll to last item.